# How to access JBOSS system properties from JAVASCRIPT framework code?

Tags: javascript, jboss, system-properties

Is it possible to point environmental variables from JavaScript(e.g react, vue, angular) during build time to JBOSS System-Properties and can be access during runtime?

**Heres my sample code:**

const RESOURCE = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ? (how???) : process.env.DEV_RESOURCE

function exampleMethod(token) {
return {
url: `${RESOURCE }/login`,
method: 'POST',
}
}

export { exampleMethod}

**Here is the screen shot of environmental variables in jboss.**

[image]